# React Native release APK crash

Tags: react-native

I have an issue with React Native 50.3 and 50.4,

I have used react-native-git-upgrade with my app it worked fine and when i run react-native run-android the app works fine

The app is fully working on React Native Version 47.2 after i upgrade the app using upgrade app when i run the release APK the app crash on open

I have tried for days now to resolve this without success. Im not really sure what is causing this issue as when i run the debug version the app works fine no issues i can find and when i go back to my build on 47.2 it works fine.

As soon as i open the installed signed APK the app crashes.

One thing i have noticed is the size of the APK when i build on 47.2 where it is working my APK is 20mb larger.

Im not getting any error with the build or signing

Can anyone help me to debug this issue or find a solution?

```
{
  "name": "APP",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "mobx": "^3.1.8",
    "mobx-react": "^4.1.5",
    "native-base": "^2.3.1",
    "react": "^16.0.0",
    "react-native": "^0.50.4",
    "react-native-collapsible": "^0.8.0",
    "react-native-drawer": "^2.3.0",
    "react-native-fcm": "^8.0.0",
    "react-native-maps": "^0.15.3",
    "react-native-svg": "^5.1.7",
    "react-native-transformable-image": "0.0.18",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^4.3.0",
    "react-navigation": "^1.0.0-beta.11"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.24.0",
    "babel-jest": "19.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.4",
    "babel-preset-flow": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "1.9.1",
    "babel-preset-react-native-stage-0": "^1.0.1",
    "jest": "19.0.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "15.4.2"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Comment: How you got out of this? i doubt react-native-maps for this. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You have to read the log of the android device. Just run `adb logcat` and you will see the throwing exception.

Comment: this command is showing lots of data which is coming continuously